# Body jump to top when open modal

Tags: javascript, css

When I click on button to open modal, in background my body go to top, I would like to stay at the first position where is red button.

Open this jsfiddle and scroll down and you will see red button, please click on him and you will notice in backgroudn body go to top, I would like to stay on button position.
I've tried to set overflow hidden for body, but not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/y7szLg65/1/

HTML

```
<h1>
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
</h1><h1>
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
</h1><h1>
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
</h1>
<button class="toggle-modal">
OPEN MODAL
</button>

<div class="modal" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- Any other Bulma elements you want -->
    <img class="video-image" src="https://png.icons8.com/color/260/car.png" alt="Video image">
  </div>
  <button class="toggle-modal modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>
</div>
<h1>
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
</h1><h1>
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut 
</h1>
```

Javascript:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-modal');
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener('click', toggleClass);
    }

function toggleClass() {
    body.classList.toggle('disable-body-scrolling');
    modal.classList.toggle('is-active');
}
```

CSS:

```
button{
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.modal {
    .toggle-modal {
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .modal-content {
        width: auto;
    }

    button.modal-close {
        top: 110px;
    }
}

.disable-body-scrolling {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That is due to the `position: fixed` applied via the `disable-body-scrolling` class ...

Comment: I'm agree with @CBroe. In order to disabled the scroll, add an overflow:hidden to the html tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your HTML tag instead of the body tag

For your javacript, change body to html:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-modal');
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener('click', toggleClass);
    }

function toggleClass() {
    html.classList.toggle('disable-html-scrolling');
    modal.classList.toggle('is-active');
}
```

And in your css change your `.disable-body-scrolling` to:

```
.disable-html-scrolling {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```